# 1 input signal, two edge detectors

Tags: flipflop, edge-detection

I have a simple rising edge detector on the top and a falling edge detector at the bottom. The switches represent low-side switched sensor. In fact, I only have one sensor. How do I use one sensor signal to trigger both rising and falling edge detector, separately? (I know I am wrong but it is like somehow the red line is connected.)

Or maybe there is a more elegant way to achieve this with a simple IC chip?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fifJeO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diodes protect the B-E junctions of Q2 and Q3 from reverse voltage, and make sure that the capacitors "reset" (discharge) properly.

Comment: I would like to know the type of input signal, is it analogue or digital (e.g. 0-5V)?

Comment: @Franc: The input is a contact closure to ground (represented by SW1), just like the OP showed in his examples.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It really helps.

Answer (score 0):

With digital signals, the transition detector used consists of the following circuit (the delay depends on the number of NOT gates and which define the duration of the pulse ):[image]